# List temporarily untracked files in git

Tags: git

I previously used

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

to temporarily untrack some of my files in git.  Now I want to list all the files that I did that for.  How can this be done?

Comment: In general you should [use `--skip-worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_skip_worktree_bit) for this, not `--assume-unchanged`. The latter is only if the file actually is unchanged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index):

> To see which files have the "assume unchanged" bit set, use `git ls-files -v` (see [git-ls-files](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files)).

Comment: I used grep to make the output more readable: `git ls-files -v | grep "^h"`